# Is a child also a dependent in IRS withholding calculator?

Tags: united-states, irs, children, withholding, form-w-4

I am trying irs.gov website's withholding calculator. I am confused with this page:

[image: page 2].

I have one minor child. Should I mention her as dependent here, "Select the number of dependents (other than yourself and your spouse ) you will claim on your tax return:" and also here "Select the number of eligible children: " ?

Answer (score 1):

These two questions are actually about two different things.

The first one is about [dependents](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p17/ch01.html#en_US_2014_publink1000170418), the second one is about [Child Tax Credit](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p972/ar02.html) .

Your dependent child does not necessarily qualify for the child tax credit (notice the "*eligible*"). Also, your dependents don't have to be your children.

Answer (score -1):

You can claim both the [child tax credit](http://www.irs.gov/Help-&-Resources/Tools-&-FAQs/FAQs-for-Individuals/Frequently-Asked-Tax-Questions-&-Answers/Child-Care-Credit,-Other-Credits/Child-Tax-Credit/Child-Tax-Credit-3) and the child and dependent care credit (for the same child/children) on the same return if you qualify for both credits.

If your dependent qualifies for the child tax credit, go ahead and enter the number